# How to select a nested element in a table with jquery with no ID and classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table with an element nested as follows:

`table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a`

None of the elements have an ID or a class.

Comment: You can pass same selector to jQuery as `$('table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a')`.

Comment: Why use jquery? Don't you want to use vanilla js selectors? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: @Adriano I have used a few jquery specific functions in my project. Might as well utilize it to the fullest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the same in jQuery as selector:-

```
$('table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a').on('click',function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

***Working sample Example:-***

```js
$('table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a').on('click',function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a id="my_id">Click Me To Get my Id!</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```